# Setting provider value in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a widget that makes a request to an api which returns a map. What I would like to do is not make the same request every time the widget is loaded and save the list to `appState.myList`. But. when I do this `appState.myList = snapshot.data;` in the `FutureBuilder`, I get the following error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for MySchedule:
flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
flutter: This ChangeNotifierProvider<MySchedule> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
flutter: framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be
flutter: built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. ...
```

`sun.dart` file:

```dart
class Sun extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<MySchedule>(context);
    var db = PostDB();

    Widget listBuild(appState) {
      final list = appState.myList;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text(list[index].title));
        },
      );
    }

    Widget futureBuild(appState) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: db.getPosts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // appState.myList = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title));
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: appState.myList != null
            ? listBuild(appState)
            : futureBuild(appState));
  }
}
```

`postService.dart` file:

```dart
class PostDB {
  var isLoading = false;

  Future<List<Postmodel>> getPosts() async {
    isLoading = true;
    final response =
        await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      isLoading = false;
      return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => Postmodel.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that the `myList` calls `notifyListeners()` and that's what causes the error. Hope I got that right. If so, how do I set `appState.myList` and use in the app without getting the above error?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:myflutter/models/post-model.dart';

class MySchedule with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Postmodel> _myList;

  List<Postmodel> get myList => _myList;

  set myList(List<Postmodel> newValue) {
    _myList = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: and where are you using setter for `myList`?

Comment: In the FutureBuilder ... `if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // appState.myList = snapshot.data;`

Comment: and why not inside `getPosts`?

Comment: yeah ... that would be even better ... but can I have `final appState = Provider.of<MySchedule>(context);` in there? I don't have context ... I never really understood what `context` does. I'm new to Flutter. Please post an answer.

Comment: i dont know, i have no experience with `Provider` class

Comment: That would help :) Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That exception arises because you are synchronously modifying a widget from its descendants.

This is bad, as it could lead to an inconsistent widget tree. Some widget. may be built widgets using the value before mutation, while others may be using the mutated value.

The solution is to remove the inconsistency. Using `ChangeNotifierProvider`, there are usually 2 scenarios:

- The mutation performed on your `ChangeNotifier` is always done within the same *build* than the one that created your `ChangeNotifier`.

  In that case, you can just do the call directly from the constructor of your `ChangeNotifier`:

  ```dart
  class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
    MyNotifier() {
      // TODO: start some request
    }
  }
  ```
- The change performed can happen "lazily" (typically after changing page).

  In that case, you should wrap your mutation in an `addPostFrameCallback` or a `Future.microtask`:

  ```dart
  class Example extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
  }

  class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
    MyNotifier notifier;

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      super.didChangeDependencies();
      final notifier = Provider.of<MyNotifier>(context);

      if (this.notifier != notifier) {
        this.notifier = notifier;
        Future.microtask(() => notifier.doSomeHttpCall());
      }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: This solution is fine. I thought that the OP only wanted to load once. In that case a `ChangeNotifier` does not seem appropriate and using `Future.microtask` to escape the calling `setState` from `build` limitation seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a problem similar to yours when using the provider. My solution is to add `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` when getting the data.

Comment: please provide an example

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `notifyListeners();` from the code. I encountered this error and that was what I did to resolve the issue.

Comment: How do you fix a code? By removing the code! Genius.

Comment: T H A N K   Y O U <3

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to handle this by using `StreamSubscription` on `Future`. It will take more boilerplate code but it can help to make sure that other logic can be separated into widget building stuff in order to prevent side effects.

```dart
Future? _dataFuture;
StreamSubscription? _dataSubscription;
```

```dart
FutureBuilder(
    future: _dataFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            // removed data updating logic from here
            // context.read<DataProvider>().updateData(newData: snapshot.data);
            case ConnectionState.done:
                return Text(
                    snapshot.data,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                );
        },
    },
),
```

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () => _getData(),
    child: const Icon(Icons.adb),
),
```

```dart
_getData() {
  _dataSubscription?.cancel();
  setState(() {
    _dataFuture = Util.getText();
    _dataSubscription = _dataFuture?.asStream().listen((data) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      context.read<DataProvider>().updateData(newData: data);
    });
  });
}
```

Check out the full sample code for this from [here](https://github.com/huynguyennovem/flutter-sample-provider-futurebuilder).