# Firebase email verification Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I know this question has been asked a lot and I have spent a lot of time reading and trying to implement the answers. So I am trying to get the response from `isEmailVerified` from Firebase Auth to work and it does work but right now it always returns false unless I refresh the app or close it and reopen it. which is obviously a bad user experience. How do I get the response to update without having to close the app.

here is the relevant pieces of code.

```
 Future<bool> isEmailVerified() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    if (user == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
     await user.reload();
     user = await _auth.currentUser();
      return user.isEmailVerified;
    }
  }
```

main.dart

```
  child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (_, auth, __) => MaterialApp(
          theme: Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context).getTheme(),
          home: FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.wait([auth.isEmailVerified(), auth.tryAutoLogin()]),
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot authResultSnapshot) =>
                authResultSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                    ? authResultSnapshot.data[1]
                        ? authResultSnapshot.data[0]
                            ? HearingsScreen()
                            : SplashScreen(
                                emailVerified: true,
                              )
                        : LoginScreen()
                    : SplashScreen(),
          ),
```

It is not returning true until I restart the app
Things I have tried besides this:
1) `await user.getIdToken(refresh: true);`
2) sign user out then back in
3) firebase_user_stream package

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try adding `notifylistener()` in `isEmailVerified()`  thats my guess

Comment: ```notifyListener()``` get stuck in  ```ConnectionState.waiting``` in my ```FutureBuilder```

Comment: u cannot generally use future builder and provider

Comment: try this by author itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359049/setting-provider-value-in-futurebuilder

Comment: I obviously did not know that ill check it out thx

Comment: can you explain why you await "_auth.currentUser" twice?

Comment: Ive done a lot  of research on this and ```_auth.currentUser(); await user.reload(); _auth.currentUser();```  was what I found to be the general accepted method to implement this auth flow 
check out this github thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20390#issuecomment-514411392

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implemented the same scenario in a splash screen with below code, you can change it as per your requirement. :

```
//To check is User is logged in
  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _fireBaseAuth.currentUser();
    if (user == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return user.isEmailVerified;
  }
```

and

```
countDownTime() async {
    return Timer(
      Duration(seconds: splashDuration),
      () async {
        if (await userAuth.isLoggedIn()) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              ScaleRoute(
                widget: HomeScreen(),),
            );
          }
        } else {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            ScaleRoute(
              widget: LoginScreen(),),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

and

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    countDownTime();
  }
```

**Update**
One needs to implement isEmailVerified in initState() function periodically which can be the ideal approach to execute the verification with firebase.

```
bool _isUserEmailVerified;
Timer _timer;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ... any code here ...
    Future(() async {
        _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()..reload();
            var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
            if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                setState((){
                    _isUserEmailVerified = user.isEmailVerified;
                });
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
    });
}

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_timer != null) {
        _timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you do an email verification in your app this is the step I am having trouble with in your example all your checking is if  the user is not null which does not guarantee ```isEmailVerified``` equals true

Comment: you can access by "user.isEmailVerified".

Comment: I guess you do not need to create new user instance in else part. The same instance defined before is sufficient to know "user.isEmailVerified".

Comment: yes I have actually implemented code very similar to this in my app but ```user.isEmailVerified``` always returns false until I close the app and restart it.

Comment: Have you tried: setState((){
                    return user.isEmailVerified;
                });

Comment: ```user.isEmailVerified``` is in my Auth class so i can't call setState but ive called ```notifyListeners();```

Comment: you should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60471750/6911538

Comment: I need to play with it more but it appears to be working the key seems to be to move the call to firebase auth ```user.isEmailVerified``` from my auth class to init state of my splash screen. If you want to take the time to amend your answer I will accept it.